# How to smooth 3ds models imported into blender

Tags: modeling, import

How do I smooth 3ds models imported to blender? I have tried the smooth shader and smooth modifiers to no success. Below are screenshots of before and after applying the smooth shader

[image: Before and after applying smoothing comparison. Smooth shader creates artifacts. How do I smooth properly without artifacts]

The following is a screenshot of the model in edit mode

[image: View in edit mode]

Comment: Could you please add some images of your topology in Edit Mode? It is kind of hard to solve the problem is without seeing your topology.

Comment: From the pictures, it looks like something is wrong with the normals. Might want to recalculate them outside, or even merge them.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the model in edit mode